# VB.NET use literal type characters bad style pros cons

Tags: vb.net, types

Is the usage of literal type characters (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9cz43ek.aspx) in VB.NET bad, old school style? I have a discussion with a pigheaded co-worker of me about that which ends up in “This is old style, I don’t wanna see it anymore!”.

My background is more technical and hardware related and I always enjoy the advantages of type-strict programming but I really think about the pros and cons in the OOP/VB world. Can some help me out with list of pros/cons?

[Update] Example usage:

```
Dim i as Integer = 0I
Dim d as Decimal = 2.4D
```

Comment: It is (very) old school and considerably harder to recognize what is being declared with `Dim n%` vs `Dim rowCount As Int32`.  Ultimately opinion based since it is functional

Comment: I've never seen "Identifier Type Characters" so personally I would never use it. I've seen "Literal Type Characters" and "Hexadecimal/Oct" often, I don't see any problem using them.

Comment: Those are the Literal Type Characters @the_lotus spoke of, not the same as the Identifier Type Characters mentioned at the top of the Link.  The Literal qualifiers are sometimes needed `Dim d = 6D`  If you want decimal, not double (`6.00`) and not integer (`6`).  'c' will be needed with  several NET methods.  Specifying a `UInt` will need them too.

Comment: Thanks for this clarification @Plutonix, I updated the question.

Comment: I would say your example isn't very good. The integer will already be ok if you just put 0, and the second will convert a decimal into a double which is a unnecessary conversion.

Comment: There is a *big* difference between helping the compiler make good decisions or produce better diagnostics and making it look like the programmer doesn't understand how the language works.  Code like this only ever draws the latter conclusion from other people that read the code.  Not typically the impression anybody ever wants to make.  This isn't otherwise the right place to get disputes resolved, teams need a coding standard that makes everybody equally unhappy.

Comment: @HansPassant Thats exact what I think too, but how to agure this compelling to someone?

Comment: Get started on writing that coding standard.

Answer (score 2):

We have two different features here:

---

**Type Characters** are a legacy feature for backwards compatibility. There are lots of people out there (including myself) who believe that they should be avoided, but it's a fully-supported feature of the language (and *not* marked as deprecated), so it's basically a matter of preference and coding style.

```
Dim myString$           ' old style
Dim myString As String  ' new style
```

Note that, here, "old style" means "*very* old style": Even [QuickBasic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QuickBASIC), the DOS predecessor of Visual Basic, already supported the "new style".

---

**Literal Type Characters** on the other hand let you specify the type of a *literal*. This is a useful feature:

```
' I explicitly want the first parameter to be a decimal, not a double.
' Without the type character, the assertion would fail.
Assert.AreEqual(3.0D, SomeMethodReturningADecimal())
```

or

```
myArray = myString.Split(";"c)   ' ";"c is a character, not a string.
```

Without the literal type characters, we'd need to use `CDec(3.0)` and `CChar(";")`, i.e., we'd need to convert these values at run-time.

In the example you mentioned in your question (variable initialization), type literals are only required if

- you need Char literals or
- you want to use type inference.

In other words, the following three statements produce exactly the same IL:

```
Dim s As Single = 1
Dim s As Single = 1.0F
Dim s = 1.0F
```

Do note that C# has literal type characters as well:

```cs
var myDecimal = 3.0m;   // This is a decimal, not a double.
```

Comment: Have you any good source for this? Like a MS webpage ore something like this? I believe this the point my co-worker wont believe in.

Comment: @sandkasten: Ask your co-worker how he would call String.Split without literal type characters.

Comment: Remember Option Strict default in VS is Off, so you can just call it like this String.Split(".")...

Comment: @sandkasten: True (and unfortunate). However, if your co-worker doesn't like old-style VB, I hope the first thing he does on every new project is to set Option Strict to On.

Comment: Inconsistently not (I allredy talked about that this too). But as longer I thought about, I belive is tilting at windmills.

Comment: You can use `CChar(";")` instead of `";".ToCharArray()(0)`.

Comment: @AndrewMorton: Thanks, that's a lot more elegant!

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen "Identifier Type Characters" so personally I would never use it. I've seen "Literal Type Characters" and "Hexadecimal/Oct" often, I don't see any problem using them when needed or if it would help someone else read your code.

This is a bit pointeless

```
    Dim i as Integer = 0I
```

But this would be needed

```
    Dim d As Decimal

    d = 13421773 / 134217728
    Console.WriteLine(d) ' Prints 0.100000001490116

    d = 13421773D / 134217728D
    Console.WriteLine(d) ' Prints 0.100000001490116119384765625

    Dim a As Char = "C" ' Compilation error with option strict on
    Dim b As Char = "C"c ' No error
```

It's also important to follow the coding standard of the group.

Comment: I don't belive the first statement is pointeless. It's only pointless if you accept that the compiler interprets the literal 0 as Integer 0. But what if the compiler vendor change the standard behaviour and interprets the literal 0 now as Integer 1? I think this would cause much trouble... (ok, this is very unrealistic but I hope you understand what I mean)

Comment: @sandkasten: I understand what you mean, and I do support `Dim d As Decimal = 0D`, but `0I` and `0.0R` are pointless because the language spec guarantees that a numeric literal without a fractional part and without a literal type character is *always* an `Int32` or `Int64` (depending on the size). Same for numbers with fractional parts and `Double`.